# Displaying a detailed post from ngFor

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, blogs

I'm creating a Blog using Angular 7, MongoDB and NodeJS. So far I have created a component that loops through all the posts from the database and displays them on a single page.

```js
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" *ngIf="posts.length > 0" >
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xl-12 text-center" *ngFor="let post of posts ">
      <div class="post-preview" >
          <h2 class="post-title text-center">
            {{ post.title }}
          </h2>
          <h3 class="post-subtitle text-center">
            {{ post.subtitle }}
          </h3>
          <br>
          <div class="post-image">
            <img [src]="post.imagePath" [alt]="post.title">
          </div>
          <br>
        <p class="post-meta text-center">{{post.date}}</p>
      </div>
      </div> 
    
  </div>
</div>
```

This is for displaying all the blog posts on a single page. When a user clicks on a single post he should be directed to a page that shows detailed information for that post only (like the blog content). How do I implement that?

In the posts.service I have the following function for getting a single post.

```js
  getPost(id: string) {
    return this.http.get<{_id: string, title: string, subtitle: string, content: string, date: Date, imagePath: string}>(
      'http://localhost:3000/api/posts/' + id);
  }
```

And on the backend I have the following route:

```js
router.get("/:id", (req, res, next) => {
  Post.findById(req.params.id).then(post => {
    if (post) {
      res.status(200).json(post);
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({
        message: 'Post not found!'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: what's the issue ? you haven't mentioned it

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: @ShashankVivek Yes I did. When a user clicks on a single post he should be directed to a page that shows detailed information for that post only (like the blog content). How do I implement that?

Comment: Try at the `TS` to make a `console.log` for the post what is there showing ?

Comment: @AldinMuratovic Did you try https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink ? you have `[routerLink]` for that

Comment: @ShashankVivek I've tried going through the angular documentation several times, I just can't figure it out :(

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/parameterised-routes/

The soloution: 
[1]
Spefify the parameterised route in router as:

```js
{ path: 'blog/:postId', component: SinglePostComponent }
```

[2]
Create a link to direct the user to the the specified blog post

```html
 <a [routerLink]="['/blog', post.id]" > </a>
```

[3]
In the SinglePostComponent.ts put the following code:

```js
export class SinglePostComponent implements OnInit {
  post: Post;
  private postId: string;


  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private postsService: PostsService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((paramMap: ParamMap) => {
      this.postId = paramMap.get('postId');
      this.postsService.getPost(this.postId).subscribe(postData => {

        this.post = {id: postData._id, title: postData.title, subtitle: postData.subtitle,
          content: postData.content, date: postData.date, imagePath: postData.imagePath};
      });

    }
    );
}


}
```